# Определить почему 1 запрос делает лишним

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii2

Не могу определить почему при отправке формы делается 2 запроса, если со второго раза отправляешь ту же форму, то получатся идет по одному запросу.
То есть отправка формы идет в модальном окне.
Моя реализация если помощет

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let url = window.location.origin;
   $('#form-condition').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       let id = $(this).data('id');
       console.log(id);
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Использую yii2 поэтому модальное окно немного по другому будет
     'editCondition',
        'header' => 'Редактировать условие'
    ]);

```
    echo $this->render('condition', compact('thema'));

Modal::end() ?>
```

И в самой форме

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form-condition',
    'options' => [
        'data-id' => $thema->id
        ]
]) ?>
<?= $form->field($thema, 'conditions')->widget(Widget::className(), [
        'settings' => [
            'lang' => 'ru',
            'buttons' => ['bold', 'italic','deleted', 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist'],
        ]
    ])->label(false) ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Редактировать', ['class' => 'createTest-modal']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Вроде бы все должно идти по одному запросу в первой формы, а не по два запроса

Как можно определить примерно почему уходить 2 запроса при первой отправке формы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы отправляете форму в 2х событиях.
Поставьте первое событие на клик кнопки по ID.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-start-now', function() {
    console.log('Нажата кнопка с div id="btn-start-now"')
    return false;
}
```